# NameError: name 'i' is not defined

Tags: python

I am getting this error when I try and run this python script.

I'm looking to display the 5th column of the list:

```
import csv
import re

with open('test.csv') as f:
       reader = csv.reader(f)
       your_list = list(reader)


for i[4] in your_list:

# x = re.search(r"\"value":(.*?),\", your_list)
        print(i)
```

Comment: just use `print(i[4])`.

Comment: getting index out of range errors, its meant to be reading in the csv and converting to list

Comment: `with open('test.csv') as f:
  for i in csv.reader(f):
    print(i[4])`

Comment: BTW, although apparently valid, using an array element as your FOR control variable is IMO bad programming practice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a list of lines and want to print out the 5th element of each line the following will work:

```
for i in your_list:
    print(i[4])
```

Each line in `your_list` is used one at a time, saved in `i` and then I print out the 5th element of that `i`, giving the 5th column

Comment: Seem to be getting index out of range errors, its meat to be reading in my csv and converting it to a list

Comment: If  that is the case then your lines don't all have 5 elements in them, so `i[4]` is trying to read beyond the line.  You could instead use `print(i)` instead just to see what each line looks like and alter your algorithm to work with those lines.

Comment: @user3296793 Make sure you specify the correct delimiter if not the default.  Like so: `for i in csv.reader(f,delimiter='|'):` assuming it's a | character.